# many IP tor in blacklist?

Tags: help

too many tor ip's have been blacklisted. When I try to login gmail, google, youtube. I'm tired of having to verify captcha constantly. Is there a way to exclude the IPs that have been blacklisted. Or can i add ip to tor?
Is using a VPN or proxy for tor a solution. Please show me how to use vpn or proxy like how to change ip on every exit.

Comment: The sites you've listed are all owned by Google/Alphabet, and are some of the most visited sites on the web. It's really not surprising that Google has become suspicious of some Tor exit nodes if they are being used by many Tor users to connect to their servers, since their whole business model is based on identifying and tracking users. There are search engines and email services out there that are more Tor friendly. See privacytools.io

Comment: There are things you can try (combine VPN with Tor, or change the way Tor exit nodes are selected), but these remove most, if not all, of the anonymity benefits Tor is designed to provide. So why are you using Tor at all?